# How to store date and time and be able to bind it to label and compare eachother

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I can't find any interesting information how to store time and date at JavaFX2 and be able to bind it to the Label. I think I can extend StringProperty for my own purpose, but I'm not sure how to implement all those methods. Also I have a list contains lots of positions and I want to be able to filter this list e.g. shows only models older than 3 years. Is there any nice way to do it?

**EDIT:**
My current solution

```
public class DateProperty extends SimpleStringProperty {

    private final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    public DateProperty() {
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    public Calendar getCalendar() {
        return calendar;
    }

    public void set(String a) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        try {
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            calendar.setTime(formatter.parse(a));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(formatter.parse(a).getTime()
                        + calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(0);
            }
        }
    }

    abstract class DateBinding extends StringBinding {
        abstract protected DateFormat getFormatter();

        @Override
        protected String computeValue() {
            return getFormatter().format(calendar.getTime());
        }
    }

    public StringBinding asDateString() {
        return new DateBinding() {
            @Override
            protected DateFormat getFormatter() {
                return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
        };
    }

    public StringBinding asTimeString() {
        return new DateBinding() {
            @Override
            protected DateFormat getFormatter() {
                return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            }
        };
    }

    public StringBinding asDateAndTimeString() {
        return new DateBinding() {
            @Override
            protected DateFormat getFormatter() {
                return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you actually have two questions here: one about how to bind labels and one on how to compare dates and times. The time and date stuff you just do in regular java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html Ps. Example code would be nice.

Comment: Is that a working answer? If so explain what it does, and add it as an answer :)